# Example of a set with countably infinite set of accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm confused by this homework problem because the answer seems extremely broad. They want an example of a set with a countably infinite set of accumulation points.

So to be countably infinite, the set must be equivalent to the set of natural numbers.

Can't the answer just be the set of real numbers since there is a point $x_0 \in R$ and an $\epsilon>0$ such that a point $x_1$ lays between $(x_0 -\epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$.

Or to be less vague, can't I say that the function $f(x) = 2x$ for all $x \in R$ is one of these sets?

Comment: You can in fact find a set whose set of accumulation points **is** the set of natural numbers.  As a start, think of a set whose only accumulation point is $1$.

Comment: hmm so could my function be $f(n) = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ since there are countably infinite amount of points from $0$ and $\lvert \frac{1}{n} \rvert$?

Comment: Your **full** set could be the set of all points $m+\frac{1}{n}$, where $m$ ranges over the natural numbers, and $n$ ranges over all integers $\ge 2$.  This set has all natural numbers as accumulation points, and no other accumulation points.

Answer (score 1):

The reals are not an example because every real is an accumulation point, which gives you an uncountable infinity of accumulation points. Can you find a subset of $\Bbb R$ that is within $(-\frac14,\frac 14)$ and has $0$ as its only accumulation point?  Can you then copy this to make the number of accumulation points you need?